# Web3j listen event from a contract

Tags: events, web3j

I want to listen to event `Sync` from a contract.

In javascript, I managed like this (this is to understand better what I want):

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

const syncEvent = contract.events["Sync"];

syncEvent().on('data', function(event){
    console.log(event);
}).on('error', function(error){
    console.log(error)
}).on("changed", function(isSyncing){
    console.log(isSyncing);
});
```

In java I managed only this:

```
Web3j web3jWS = Web3j.build(new WebSocketService("wss://...", false));

EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(
    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,
    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,
    contractAddress
);
```

But I have no idea how to continue this, even if it's right my code.

How I can listen to the event `Sync` with Web3j?

Comment: How are you fetching the contract address?  Also I think your filter will want to change the first `DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,` to `DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST,`.

Comment: @ruby_newbie The contractAddress is a string in my code `String contractAddress = "0x2b4c76d0dc16be1c31d4c1dc53bf9b45987fc75c"` . It's from Fantom Blockchain.

Comment: Did you try removing the `0x` prefix from the address?

Comment: @ruby_newbie It's pointless since my code is not completely.